# how to fill each structure of my array of structures with cycle-for and scanf?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, structure

I am new on this website and it looks cool.

I have this issue where I want to make a program where the user decides how many books to declare, next  the user fills the info for each book requested (e.g.: user wants 3 books, so he fills in all the info for these 3 books).

I think I need an array structure, but i do not have any idea how to loop through this filling process.

This is my code:

```
struct book
    {
    char bname[20];
    int pages;
    char author[20];
    long price; 
};

printf("enter number of books to store");
scanf("%d",&unumber);
for (i=0;i<number_of_books;i++) {printf's and scanf's to fill each struct}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading input within a loop, one primary area of concern is insuring `stdin` is flushed following each read to prevent the trailing `newline` from being interpreted as input to the next `read` statement. There a many ways to do this, however, using `scanf` the easiest way is through a carefully crafted `format` statement that consumes the trailing `newline`. The following illustrates this method:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXS 256

struct book
{
    char bname[20];
    int pages;
    char author[20];
    long price; 
};

int main () {

    struct book books[MAXS] = {{ {0}, 0, {0}, 0 }}; /* initialize all values to zero (null) */
    int nbooks = 0;
    int i = 0;

    printf ("\nEnter number of books to store: ");
    scanf("%d%*c",&nbooks);                         /* read nbooks, and consume newline     */

    if (nbooks < 1) {                               /* validate number of books to enter    */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid entry for 'nbooks'\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nbooks; i++)                    /* enter values for each book, use      */
    {                                               /* scanf to read each value AND the     */
        printf ("\n  book[%2d] name  : ", i + 1);   /* newline character, emptying stdin    */
        scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", books[i].bname);        /* after each read.                     */
        printf ("  book[%2d] pages : ", i + 1);
        scanf ("%d%*c", &books[i].pages);
        printf ("  book[%2d] author: ", i + 1);
        scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", books[i].author);
        printf ("  book[%2d] price : ", i + 1);
        scanf ("%ld%*c", &books[i].price);
    }

    printf ("\n\nThe Books Entered Were:\n");       /* output info for each book entered    */
    i = 0;
    while (*books[i].bname)
    {
        printf ("\n  Book %-3d \"%s\"\n", i + 1, books[i].bname);
        printf ("    author : %s\n", books[i].author);
        printf ("    pages  : %d\n", books[i].pages);
        printf ("    price  : %ld\n", books[i].price);
        i++;
    }

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/books

Enter number of books to store: 2

  book[ 1] name  : Tom Sawyer
  book[ 1] pages : 321
  book[ 1] author: Mark Twain
  book[ 1] price : 2199

  book[ 2] name  : Huckelberry Finn
  book[ 2] pages : 298
  book[ 2] author: Mark Twain
  book[ 2] price : 1999


The Books Entered Were:

  Book 1   "Tom Sawyer"
    author : Mark Twain
    pages  : 321
    price  : 2199

  Book 2   "Huckelberry Finn"
    author : Mark Twain
    pages  : 298
    price  : 1999
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do so. one is simple using array of book structure another using linked list. Below, I am giving you both solution:

**First solution using structure array:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXBOOKS 100

struct book {
     char bname[20];
     int pages;
     char author[20];
     long price;
};

int main()
{
     struct book books[MAXBOOKS];
     int number_of_books;
     printf("enter number of books to store\n");
     scanf("%d",&number_of_books);

     // writing books
     for (int i=0;i<number_of_books;i++) {
            printf("Enter new book record: Book_Name, Pages, Author, Price\n");
            scanf("%s %d %s %ld",books[i].bname, &books[i].pages, books[i].author, &books[i].price);

     }


     //reading books
     printf("Entered books records: Book_Name, Pages, Author, Price\n");
     for (int i=0;i<number_of_books;i++) {
            printf("%s\t %d\t %s\t %ld\n",books[i].bname, books[i].pages, books[i].author, books[i].price);

     }

     return 0;
 }
```

**Second solution using Linked list:**
you can store all books as linked list. add one extra data field next which points next node book.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct book { 
      char bname[20];
      int pages; 
      char author[20];
      long price; 
      struct book *next; 
};

int main()
{
     int number_of_books;
     printf("enter number of books to store");
     scanf("%d",&number_of_books);
     struct book *head, *temp,*curnode;
     head=NULL;
     temp=NULL;
     for (int i=0;i<number_of_books;i++) {
         // writing books
         temp=(struct book *)malloc(sizeof(struct book));
         printf("Enter new book record: Book_Name, Pages, Author, Price\n");
         scanf("%s %d %s %ld",temp->bname, &temp->pages, temp->author, &temp->price);
         temp->next=NULL;
         if(head==NULL){
             printf("in head if");
             head=temp;
             curnode=temp;
         } else {
             curnode->next=temp;
             curnode=curnode->next;
      }
   }


     //reading books
     temp=head;
     while(temp!=NULL){
         printf("%s\t %d\t %s\t %ld",temp->bname, temp->pages, temp->author, temp->price);
         printf("\n");

         temp=temp->next;

      }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the book name has a space in it, `scanf("%s %d %s %d",temp->bname...` will not work.

Comment: @kriyeta i'm attempting to run your code but it returns me an error, it's alright with the mallocs declarations?

Comment: It is never wise to complicate the answer to a simple question by introducing an abstract data structure not called for by the question. It just adds unnecessary confusion.

Comment: @Jey I modified code it's running now. you can also do it using array of structure.